# RTMP streaming in Electron (atom-shell)

Tags: flash, jwplayer, video.js, rtmp, electron

I’m working on an Electron project where the main focus is to present video streams in RTMP format to the users.

I’ve been following some guides; [atom/electron’s official guide; “Using Pepper Flash Plugin”](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-pepper-flash-plugin.md) as well as [this example app’s slightly more detailed walkthrough](https://github.com/hokein/electron-sample-apps/tree/master/pepper-flash-plugin), and I’ve gotten Flash working in Electron. I’ve been able to load various sites into my main `BrowserWindow` and I’ve witnessed Pepper Flash playing movies in all its glory.

However, I’m banging my head against the wall trying to implement a self-hosted player within Electron. I’ve tried JWPlayer and video.js thus far, and all resources are loading nicely – for a brief moment.

**JWPlayer**

Flash player is visibly there, then it fails and displays an error message; “Flash plugin failed to load”.

**video.js**

Flash player is visibly there, but doesn’t react to anything – not pushing the play button, not calling `player.play()`. Nothing.

**Common**

I’ve not seen so much as a glimpse of a frame from any of our available streams, be it live or vod ones.

I’ve tried massaging my stream URLs as described in both [JWPlayer’s](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1430358-using-rtmp-streaming) and [video.js’](http://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/tech.html#flash-technology) docs, but no cigar.

I’m fresh out of imagination, and in need a fresh – or experienced – pair of eyes on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jakub Szwacz [explains it all in an understandable way, and also provides a solution](https://github.com/szwacz/nw-flash-trust). I fixed an issue in a new Electron project today, and just now realized it’s the same as this one – I just didn’t understand what was wrong the way [funrob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/275375/funrob) was trying to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the Flash plugin is being blocked. We display the “Flash plugin failed to load” error message when JavaScript does not receive an ExternalInterface call from ActionScript in jwplayer.flash.swf more than 4 seconds after it has been embedded. This can simply be a network issue if the swf cant load in time, but it's more likely another problem withe browser (electron) blocking execution of the Flash plugin or it's communication with JavaScript.

I'm not sure which version of Chrome/Pepper Flash ships with electron currently, but since October of 2015, execution of the plugin is throttled under certain circumstances. Here's a write up on this "Power Saving" feature: http://www.jwplayer.com/blog/chrome-power-saving/

Make sure the swf is not hosted cross-domain or on a different protocol than the page it's embedded in. Flash security sandbox violations will prevent Flash from being able to execute JS or load external media streams.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @funrob! As I detailed above, the Flash plugin does indeed work inside my Electron app, with external content such as Adobe’s own demo pages as well as in my app now, with Flow Player, of which I’m not the biggest fan. The player does visually appear when using JW Player (swf loaded?), but 4 seconds sounds too familiar – are there any circumstances where the swf will load but not emit all the stuff it’s supposed to? The details on power saving is interesting, as all my videos are rather small – but then again, the same size works with Flow Player.

Comment: Oh, and I’m on the same team as this guy whose ticket you closed over at GitHub, @funrob; [RTMP (flash) through file://some_file.html crashes the flash player](https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer/issues/1030). We suspect it was closed for the wrong reason, as we’re not trying to stream local resources.